# UILabel sizeToFit not retained when back button pressed to go back to rootViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uilabel

So my rootViewController contains a UICollectionView with a Custom UICollectionViewCell.  I have a label on the cell for a header which shouldn't ever change and I have a multi-line Label making up the body of the rest of the cell.  When I launch the app it calls the sizeToFit correctly and top aligns everything so it isn't centered.  I click on one of the cells and go to the next view, then if I click the back button to go back to the rootViewController it does run the viewWillAppear method and reloads the data but the sizeToFit does not work and everything on the multi-line label becomes center aligned.  It is still multiple lines but if there is only a couple of lines it sits in the center of the label and it doesn't look good.  How can I keep this so it is consistant.  I have a left menu that will reload the rootViewController which will position the label correctly again but once I hit the back button from the secondViewController it is no longer aligned.  Is there a way to make it clear all of the cells and reload them.  I have tried the [collectionView reloadData]; in the viewWillAppear and it doesn't work, it is currently called at the end of the connectionDidFinish which the network connection is called from the viewWillAppear method.  Any assistance is appreciated.

This is the custom UICollectionViewCell code

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    [contentLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [contentLabel sizeToFit];
}
```

RootViewController

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"LocationListCell";
    LocationList *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier 
                                                           forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.titleBar setText:[value objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSArray *tempObject = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self getData:[key   
                                           objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    NSMutableString *tempString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [tempObject count]; i++)
    {
        [tempString appendString:[tempObject objectAtIndex:i]];
        [tempString appendString:@"\r"];
    }
    //[cell.contentLabel sizeToFit];
    //[cell.contentLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [cell.contentLabel setText:tempString];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Share some code related to make label on cell...

Comment: Update your question with the code.

Comment: @Jarod what you want exactly?? means you want to dynamic UILable??

Comment: So how would I go about that?  I mean when it first loads it looks right, why is it when the 2nd view controller is poped off the stack the rootViewController doesn't maintain its attributes of how it looked previous before pushing the second view controller?

Comment: just try and use the dynamic UILable with my method , it just an idea which may be useful to you dude... :)

Comment: I am seeing similar, curious as to why this happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this dynamic `UILable` with this custom method...

just add this bellow method in your `.m` file

```
-(float) calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:(NSString*) text: (UIFont*)withFont: (float)width :(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
{
[text retain];
[withFont retain];
CGSize suggestedSize = [text sizeWithFont:withFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];

[text release];
[withFont release];

return suggestedSize.height;
}
```

and use it like bellow..

```
   UILabel *yourLable = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [yourLable setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 31, 200, 50)];        
    [yourLable setText:tempString];
    yourLable.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    yourLable.numberOfLines = 0;
    yourLable.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];

    yourLable.frame = CGRectMake(yourLable.frame.origin.x, yourLable.frame.origin.y, 
                             200,[self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:yourLable.text :yourLable.font :200 :UILineBreakModeWordWrap]  ); 


    yourLable.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

     cell.contentLabel = yourLable;
```

hope this help you...

Comment: This code actually is showing me where the problem is.  It has to do with the cells reuse but I haven't figured out what is causing it.  Because some of the cells are not getting anything set the first time on the label that when the label is added the next time the nib isn't being called.  Doing some more testing.

Comment: How do I have it just create and not reuse a cell?  I am not seeing any way of doing that?

Comment: Is there a way to change from this?

LocationList *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: @Jarod just put dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:nil just set as a nil here try it..

Comment: @Jarod and also just add lable programmatically  in cellForItemAtIndexPath method dude try it.. i think that'll work dude...

Comment: adding the label the way you pasted in for code still behaved the same way.  making the identifier set to nil crashes the app

must pass a valid reuse identifier to -[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:]

Comment: hey dude.. add this lable to cell like [cell..contentView addSubview: yourLable]; and first set text at starting to alloc the lable and then calculate the size dude.. it must work bcoz i used it dude..

Comment: hey dude.. add this lable to cell like [cell..contentView addSubview: yourLable]; and first set text at starting to alloc the lable and then calculate the size dude.. it must work bcoz i used it dude..

Comment: UILineBreakModeWordWrap is deprecated in IOS6

Comment: then comment it and try the code .. just change something which not useful to you dude..

Comment: Like I said I already implemented this and I received the same behavior as if I had done the UILabel in the Interface Builder.  Your code provided does the same thing, whenever it calls a the reuse everything moves down to the center away from the top.

Comment: sorry you call the method just try with updated answer i just skip one method with call it dude sorry...

Comment: its also works fine in my UITableView and its very easy to use for create programaticly the UILable and set frame like this code..

Comment: @Jarod also see my this blog with this small code.. http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/11/set-uilabel-with-adjust-content-text.html

Comment: Maybe you could answer this because this would be easier to do.  How come I cannot implement a textView instead of a label which will put the top Left Alignment that I want.  I keep getting a BAD_ACCESS exception whenever I place a textView on the CollectionViewCell.  I think the object is just being removed since I am using ARC.

Comment: then this is the best example to use dynamic uilable instead of UItextView dude.. but i dont know where u going wrong but not use retain and relese keyword and also autorelese if you use ARC dude just comment that line which contain retain,relese keyword..

Answer (score 0):

Try these lines:

```
contentLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
 contentLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

Comment: Both of these functions are depricated in iOS 6

Comment: [contentLabel setNumberOfLines:5]; Try it.

Comment: Well I have more than 5 lines but when I limit it it behaves the same.  When I first load the view it is top aligned and when I go to the second view controller and then go back to the root view controller they are all center aligned.

Comment: I just set the frame in the Interface Builder.  Should I be setting it in the m file where I am setting the sizeToFit?

Comment: Means you not make label programmatically?

Comment: if u not make label programmatically then make label programmatically and set frame in .m file then try

Comment: Correct but I just set the frame of it exactly like I have in Interface Builder and it is still the same behavior.

    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        // Drawing code
        CGRect lblFrame = CGRectMake(10, 49, 202, 237);
        [contentLabel setFrame:lblFrame];
        [contentLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
        [contentLabel sizeToFit];
    }

Comment: Same behavior as if I set it in Interface Builder.

Comment: Delete label from interface & make it programmatically before this line: [cell.contentLabel setText:tempString];

Comment: or you can put these lines in viewwillappear method: [contentLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [contentLabel sizeToFit]; then check...

Comment: How do I add it to the Cell programmatically?  I have created it but can't figure out how to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that and declare label in .h file

```
contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 49, 202, 237)];
 [contentLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [contentLabel sizeToFit];
  [cell.contentLabel setText:tempString];
```

Comment: Which .h file should have that?  The rootViewController or the .h file for the custom cell?

Comment: Here is what I have defined in my .m file for the rootViewController

CGRect lblFrame = CGRectMake(10, 49, 202, 237);
    contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lblFrame];
    [contentLabel setFrame:lblFrame];
    [contentLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [contentLabel sizeToFit];
    [cell addSubview:contentLabel];
    [contentLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [contentLabel setText:tempString];


Then in the .h file I have this

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *contentLabel;

I don't see the label.

Comment: dont declare as iboutlet simple in .h declare UILable *labelname;

Comment: and write my code in m file before: [cell.contentLabel setText:tempString];

Comment: Still isn't showing in the cell.  Is the addSubView the correct implementation?

CGRect lblFrame = CGRectMake(10, 49, 202, 237);
    contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lblFrame];
    [contentLabel setFrame:lblFrame];
    [contentLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [contentLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [contentLabel sizeToFit];
    [contentLabel setText:tempString];
    [cell addSubview:contentLabel];
    return cell;

Comment: like that:contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 49, 202, 237)];
 [contentLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [contentLabel sizeToFit];  [cell addSubview:contentLabel];
  [cell.contentLabel setText:tempString];

Comment: This line [cell addSubview:contentLabel]; add it after [cell.contentLabel setText:tempString];

Comment: cell.contentLabel is no longer a label since you had me delete it from the Interface Builder.

Comment: Yea I did create it programmatically but it would no longer be a property of Cell that I can set.

This is what I have so far but still can't see text:
contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 49, 202, 237)];
    [contentLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [contentLabel sizeToFit];
    [contentLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [contentLabel setText:tempString];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:contentLabel];
    return cell;

Comment: See like that comment and do like that in -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method

Comment: It still isn't working.  Can we just explain why it doesn't maintain when I have it setup the other way?  Why do you think changing it so that I add the label programmatically that it will behave any different?

Comment: No reason but adding programmatically is good way speciaally in this kind of situation thats why I always make button,label,imageview programmatically...

Comment: You can use interface no issue but try to written label property in viewwillapper method and then check...

Comment: That means that I would have to create the label in the rootViewController and not in the custom Cell.  However, I can't seem to get a label created in the rootViewController to display on the custom cell.